# Prevent Buefy / Bulma modal from closing when clicking outside in VueJS / NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, bulma, buefy, nuxtjs

The default behaviour of a Buefy Modal is to close when clicking outside (or pressing ESC).
However this behaviour could be detrimental when dealing with long inputs cause a wrong click could make the user lose all its work.

How do you prevent a Buefy Modal from closing when clicking outside (in VueJS / NustJS) ?

In the example below, I created a custom component that contains the modal (card modal: https://buefy.org/documentation/modal ). then in the parent page I open the modal with the following function:

```js
methods: {
    createNew(type) {
      this.$store.commit('SET_MODAL_TYPE', type)
      this.$buefy.modal.open({
        parent: this,
        component: createNewModal,
        hasModalCard: true,
        customClass: 'custom-class custom-class-2',
        trapFocus: true,
      })
    },
  },
```

UPDATE:

As per the accepted answer, the solution was quite easy, just add `canCancel: ['x']` when calling the modal:

```js
  methods: {
    createNew(type) {
      this.$store.commit('SET_MODAL_TYPE', type)
      this.$buefy.modal.open({
        parent: this,
        component: createNewModal,
        hasModalCard: true,
        trapFocus: true,
        canCancel: ['x'],
      })
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `can-cancel` prop to define what can cause modal close: `can-cancel="['escape', 'x', 'outside']"`

[Docs](https://buefy.org/documentation/modal/#api-view)

Comment: Uh I missed that, thanks! I'll try in the morning and let you know. :)